# AVAudioPlayer not releasing memory when expected

Tags: loops, delegates, avaudioplayer

I am writing a "narrator" type app, which reads out every sentence in a paragraph in sequence. TO achieve this, I have the following:

```
- (void) startSentPlayLoop {
    _isInPlayingLoop = YES;
    _currentlyPlayingSentNo=-1;
    [self audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:nil successfully:NO];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    if (_isInPlayingLoop) {
        _currentlyPlayingSentNo++;
        [LMAudioPlayer playAudioFileForSent:_currentlyPlayingSentNo withDelegateAs:self];
     }
}
```

and in File LMAudioPlayer.m

```
+ (void) playAudioFileForSent:(int)sentNo withDelegateAs:(id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>)delegate {
    AVAudioPlayer* audioInstance = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[self urlFromSentNo] error:&error];
    audioInstance.delegate = delegate;
    [audioInstance play];
}
```

Its all working well. I noticed in Instruments that upon playing, say, ten sentences, ten AVAudioPlayer instances get created (a new one for every sentence), and all of them get released when all sentences are exhausted (kinda building a stack, and eventually calling popAll()). I guessed this is because in audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method, I am calling playAudioFileForSent, which creates a kinda recursion.

To avoid this (I would want one sentence play to finish, release the memory and then start the next sentence), I tried moving the playAudioFileForSent method call to s separate loop, but with no change. FOllowing is my revised code:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    if (_isInPlayingLoop) {
        _currentlyPlayingSentNo++;
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(playNextSentenceInLoop:) withObject:nil];
     }
}

- (void)playNextSentenceInLoop:(id)sender {
    [LMAudioPlayer playAudioFileForSent:_currentlyPlayingSentNo withDelegateAs:self];
}
```

So, I guessed that if I let the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method return, and call the playAudioFileForSent in a new thread, the recursion stack buildup may be avoided. This didnt happen, and I am still getting the same situation - the stack builds up and then demolishes all at once. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line here:

```
AVAudioPlayer* audioInstance = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[self urlFromSentNo] error:&error];
```

is what's creating multiple copies of "AVAudioPlayer".

If you want to save memory, you need to figure out a way to re-use your "`audioInstance`" object instead of creating a new one each time that method is called.

My suggestion would be to make "`audioInstance`" a property or ivar (instance variable) and then if it already exists, reset it to the contents of the new URL when your previous audio file is done and then restart playing.

Comment: and how to reset it to different content? I do not think there is a way to do it, cause you init with it.

Comment: thanks for the "-1" @BorisGafurov ! If you look at the [documentation for AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/avaudioplayerclassreference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-SW10), you'll see the only way to set the player's content is to do what I just suggested (the content gets set at `init` time). You cannot reset the content of an already instantiated AVAudioPlayer object.

Comment: That was my point too, content is set. you simply release audioInstance when finished playing, that is all and start it all over again. Your wording "... reset it to ..." may be too ambiguous. please edit it I will retract my vote.